# Union of two arrays equals the first array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am doing a problem from projecteuler.com. The question is this:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the
>   sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

I thought of creating arrays of multiples for each 3 and 5 up to 1000 and taking the union of them, which doesn't leave me with duplicates (so I don't need to call `array.uniq`). What I've written is this:

```
def get_range(range, step)
  ret = []
  range.step(step) { |i| ret << i }
  return ret
end
p get_range(0..1000, 3) | get_range(0..1000, 5)
```

This comes out with this result:

> [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87, 90, 93, 96, 99, 102, 105, 108, 111, 114, 117, 120, 123, 126, 129, 132, 135, 138, 141, 144, 147, 150, 153, 156, 159, 162, 165, 168, 171, 174, 177, 180, 183, 186, 189, 192, 195, 198, 201, 204, 207, 210, 213, 216, 219, 222, 225, 228, 231, 234, 237, 240, 243, 246, 249, 252, 255, 258, 261, 264, 267, 270, 273, 276, 279, 282, 285, 288, 291, 294, 297, 300, 303, 306, 309, 312, 315, 318, 321, 324, 327, 330, 333, 336, 339, 342, 345, 348, 351, 354, 357, 360, 363, 366, 369, 372, 375, 378, 381, 384, 387, 390, 393, 396, 399, 402, 405, 408, 411, 414, 417, 420, 423, 426, 429, 432, 435, 438, 441, 444, 447, 450, 453, 456, 459, 462, 465, 468, 471, 474, 477, 480, 483, 486, 489, 492, 495, 498, 501, 504, 507, 510, 513, 516, 519, 522, 525, 528, 531, 534, 537, 540, 543, 546, 549, 552, 555, 558, 561, 564, 567, 570, 573, 576, 579, 582, 585, 588, 591, 594, 597, 600, 603, 606, 609, 612, 615, 618, 621, 624, 627, 630, 633, 636, 639, 642, 645, 648, 651, 654, 657, 660, 663, 666, 669, 672, 675, 678, 681, 684, 687, 690, 693, 696, 699, 702, 705, 708, 711, 714, 717, 720, 723, 726, 729, 732, 735, 738, 741, 744, 747, 750, 753, 756, 759, 762, 765, 768, 771, 774, 777, 780, 783, 786, 789, 792, 795, 798, 801, 804, 807, 810, 813, 816, 819, 822, 825, 828, 831, 834, 837, 840, 843, 846, 849, 852, 855, 858, 861, 864, 867, 870, 873, 876, 879, 882, 885, 888, 891, 894, 897, 900, 903, 906, 909, 912, 915, 918, 921, 924, 927, 930, 933, 936, 939, 942, 945, 948, 951, 954, 957, 960, 963, 966, 969, 972, 975, 978, 981, 984, 987, 990, 993, 996, 999, 5, 10, 20, 25, 35, 40, 50, 55, 65, 70, 80, 85, 95, 100, 110, 115, 125, 130, 140, 145, 155, 160, 170, 175, 185, 190, 200, 205, 215, 220, 230, 235, 245, 250, 260, 265, 275, 280, 290, 295, 305, 310, 320, 325, 335, 340, 350, 355, 365, 370, 380, 385, 395, 400, 410, 415, 425, 430, 440, 445, 455, 460, 470, 475, 485, 490, 500, 505, 515, 520, 530, 535, 545, 550, 560, 565, 575, 580, 590, 595, 605, 610, 620, 625, 635, 640, 650, 655, 665, 670, 680, 685, 695, 700, 710, 715, 725, 730, 740, 745, 755, 760, 770, 775, 785, 790, 800, 805, 815, 820, 830, 835, 845, 850, 860, 865, 875, 880, 890, 895, 905, 910, 920, 925, 935, 940, 950, 955, 965, 970, 980, 985, 995]

which is the first array. If I swap the order of the ranges, then I get the array with the multiples of 5. I tried something like this on IRB:

```
[1,3,5] | [3, 5, 7]
# => [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Am I missing something, am I just going insane, or have I encountered a bug in Ruby?

Comment: Don't easily claim a bug. You are just a beginner. Judging from your carelessness seen in this question, you will most likely never find a real bug in Ruby.

Comment: Instead of providing a sample that tests from 0..1000, why not do 0..10 or 0..100? The redundancy doesn't help clarify the problem, but it does clutter the question and make us wade through a lot more unnecessary information. Conciseness is important when asking a question. Also, the idea when doing the on-line programming challenges, is for YOU to solve them on your own, not to ask for help solving them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is correct. It contains both multiples of 3 **and** 5. Look at the end. It's just not sorted.

Comment: Doh, I feel like an idiot. Thank you. /facepalm